Why is my nextflow script executed sequentially?
I have the following Nextflow script:
nextflow.enable.dsl=2
include { check_folders; downloadClinvar; downloadReferenceGenome; downloadBedFiles; downloadGatkVcfFiles } from '/home/user/Desktop/pipeline/download_data.nf'
workflow {
    check_folders()
    downloadClinvar(check_folders.out)
    downloadReferenceGenome(check_folders.out)
    downloadBedFiles(check_folders.out)
    downloadGatkVcfFiles(check_folders.out)
}

The graph that is generated for me using the -preview -with-dag flags is the following:

When I run the workflow it works fine but it performs each step sequentially, and I want it to download everything at the same time.
What could be happening to me? Why is my nextflow script executed sequentially?

Show the content of these nf scripts and how you run the script nextflow run...

Cross-posting should be indicated https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22475/why-is-my-nextflow-script-executed-sequentially

In addition to the .nf script, can you please also .config file? Maybe the number of forks is set to 1?

Not that I'm doubting you but can you share the evidence that it is run sequentially? do each step takes long enough that it obvious that nf should have tried to run it in sequence. If you run it -with-trace you should get. In any case is possible that by the default configuration a nextflow script would be run in sequence, for example if queueSize is set to 1 or the default executor has. a limited number of threads (perhaps 'local' in some circumstances).
